# SQL : Add Value into an alias (from using the AS keyword)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help in constructing an SQL Statement where in I have to connect/reference a value to an Alias I created.

So I have a table named Employee and has fields

> EmpID (Primary key),  LastName,  FirstName,  MiddleName

I joined the 3 and here's the SQL Statement:

```
Select LastName+', '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName  AS EmployeeName
```

Now I need to reference the EmployeeName and set it's value to EmpID because it's the primary key

I need it to fill in a Dropdown List that should show the Employee names but the value is the EmpID:

```
DropListEmployeeName.DataTextField = "EmployeeName";
DropListEmployeeName.DataValueField = "EmpID";
DropListEmployeeName.DataBind();
DropListEmployeeName.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

Please suggest the proper SQL statement.

Comment: This problem is an issue for the client side User interface, which depends totally on what client side user interface language/technology you are using.

Comment: which do you have, `mysql` or microsoft `sql-server` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write this query.

```
Select EmpId, LastName+', '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName AS EmployeeName
from Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

**Join column** with any **separator** and give **alias** name:

```
Select LastName+', '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName AS EmpId FROM Employee
```